# CLIPS: recent version of CLIPSLib.dll (x64)

Tags: c#, clips

Greetings and Salutations,

I am looking to embed CLIPS in a .net application (via C#) and I am using two DLLs; **CLIPSNet.dll** and **CLIPSLib.dll**

When I try to run the program, it appears that the CLIPSNet.dll is assimilated successfully, but when it reaches to the CLIPSLib.dll, I get errors complaining about the architecture the DLL was compiled in (x86 instead of the expected x64).

I found several threads from several years ago that usually ended with the suggestion to recompile the source and it will work fine.

I do not have the facilities to recompile the source code myself, and a colleague of mine tried to do it for me and he encountered numerous errors in the source.

If anyone in the community has successfully recompiled the CLIPSLib.dll in the x64 architecture, could I impose upon you to please provide a link to the DLL or please email it to me?

Thank you very much, in advance!

Cheers,
Chief_Ed

Comment: Here is CLIPSNet https://github.com/yifeitao/CLIPSNet, including ManagedCLIPS project. Easy compiled for both x86 and x64 platforms, much warnings, but nothing related to exactly x64 platform. I tried with both 2013 community and 2017 community for both x86 and x64 platforms, at least i can compile without problems (have to switch to v120 build tools for vs 2013 community)

Comment: Thank yhou vwery much! So all I have to do is get a membership to Github in order to download the CLIPSLib.dll?

Comment: Sorry for the fat finger typing errors...

Comment: Sorry, did not read internet 2 days :-) No, you not need membership and not need even git  software: just open code tab, find button "Clone or Download" and  download zip. I tried to get direct link, but they have relative path in href, had not success